# How to use getfeatureinfo with MapServer and OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver, getfeatureinfo

I'm trying to use the `getfeatureinfo` function of Openlayers with `MapServer`. When I click on a point on my map, I get the following error in Firebug:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/exception_1_1_1.dtd">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
<ServiceException code="LayerNotQueryable">
msWMSFeatureInfo(): WMS server error. Requested layer(s) are not queryable.
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I've included the javascript and mapfile that I am using. As far as I can tell, I have the correct arguments in my Mapfile but it does not appear to enable querying using `getfeatureinfo`. I'm also a little unclear on how my html templates should be structured or if they are essential for this.

This is the javascript (I am using OpenLayers 2.12):

```
    info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
    url: 'http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?MAP=points.map', 
    title: 'Identify features by clicking',
    queryVisible: true,
    eventListeners: {
        getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
           console.log(event.text)                  
        }
    }
});
map.addControl(info);
info.activate();
```

And this is my mapfile, `points.map`:

```
MAP
  IMAGETYPE      PNG
  EXTENT         -9780000 2770000 -8850000 3650000  
  SIZE           500 600
  SHAPEPATH      "/home/data"
  IMAGECOLOR     255 255 255
  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:900913"
  END
  CONFIG          "MS_ERRORFILE" "/home/tmp/ms_error.txt"
  DEBUG 5         
  WEB
    METADATA
        "wms_title"           "WMS Demo Server"
        "wms_onlineresource"  "http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?MAP=points.map&"
        "wms_srs"             "EPSG:900913"
        "wms_enable_request"  "*"
        "ows_enable_request"  "*"
    END
  END

  ##### symbol definition
  SYMBOL
    NAME "circle"
    TYPE ellipse
    FILLED true
    POINTS
        1 1
    END
  END

  ####### layer
  LAYER 
    NAME            points
    CONNECTIONTYPE  POSTGIS
    CONNECTION      "host=localhost dbname=data user=postgres port=5432"
    DATA            "geom from points using unique gid using SRID=3086"
    HEADER          'head.html'  
    FOOTER          'foot.html'
    METADATA        
        "wms_enable_request" "*"    
        "gml_include_items" "all"
        "wms_include_items" "all"           
    END  
    STATUS          ON
    TYPE            POINT
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:3086"
    END
    CLASS
      NAME 'point symbols'
      STYLE
        SYMBOL "circle"
        COLOR         100 100 100
        OUTLINECOLOR  10  10  10
        SIZE 50
      END
    END
  END    
END
```

My template files are very basic - just `<html><body>` for the `HEADER` and `</body></html>` for the `FOOTER`.

Where am I going wrong in this overall process?

Answer (score 3):

If I have understood your question, you have created the HEADER and the FOOTER files, but not the [TEMPLATE](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html) one. The latter file is mandatory, and in your scenario it 'generates' the contents of HTML's body.

Besides, inside the LAYER object of your mapfile there should also be a reference to the template file, given via TEMPLATE.

For point based queries, it is advisable you also include inside the LAYER object TOLERANCE and TOLERANCEUNITS.

Comment: ah ok. Thanks for the suggestion. I just added `TEMPLATE "body.html"` into my mapfile and created an empty file 'body.htmll'. I'm still getting the error that my layer is not queryable though.

Comment: Given that you are using MapServer 5, try to set DUMP to "true" in the LAYER object; by default, DUMP is set to "false".

Comment: `DUMP "true"` appears to be deprecated http://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html (and pink tiles were overlaid on map).

Comment: According to documentation (http://goo.gl/lSKKc), DUMP is deprecated in MapServer version 6 and later, not in MapServer version 5.

Comment: I'm using the most recent Mapserver version (6.0.3)